# Tying Array elemsnts to actual text fields on a Form

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a PDF Form with several lines representing jobs and payments.

All lines are in the Array:

```
var Line = [{ Job: "function", Time: "hours", Wage: "pay" }];
```

`function`, `hours` and `pay` are names of a set of text fields on each line of the Form.

How can I tie the index of an element of Line to a certain set of text fields the Form? (Like: `Line[10]`.Time refers to the text field `hours` on the 10th line of text fields on the form )

Or is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: To be able to access each of the text fields (in order to read, calculate and change contents) through statements such as:   this.getField(Line[7].pay).value = 150;

Comment: Do you mean `Line[7].Wage`? Why do you try to reference the `.name` of form element using value of object, instead of property name of object?

Comment: I can use the property name. My main problem is how to make a correspondence between an element in the array using a specific array  index and the corresponding line of text fields on the Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate each parent element of "line" containing sets of `<input>` or `<select>` elements, set value of each property of object by utilizing attribute begins with selector `[attrName^=attrValye]` to match elements corresponding to previously set values of object, then set the value of object property to the matched element.

You can then set value of element by referencing index of `Line` array, and property of object.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("lines");
const fields = lines.querySelectorAll("fieldset")
const Line = Array.from(fields
             , function(field) { 
                 let o = {Job: "function", Time: "hours", Wage: "pay"};
                 for (let prop in o) 
                   o[prop] = field.querySelector(`[name^="${o[prop]}"]`);                                  
                 return o
             });

Line[0].Job.value = "abc";
Line[1].Time.value = 123;
```

```html
<form id="lines">
  <fieldset>
    <input name="function[0]" type="text">
    <input name="hours[0]" type="number">
    <input name="pay[0]" type="number">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input name="function[1]" type="text">
    <input name="hours[1]" type="number">
    <input name="pay[1]" type="number">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the presented idea. But with a couple of hundred lines this will be somewhat tedious. I was thinking of something more in the direction of creating the text fields on the fly when initializing and populating  a new element of the Line array. I just don't know how to create the text fields on the fly, position them on the page programmatically so that the appear aligned on the page, etc.

Comment: @user1513422 The original Question does not ask how to dynamically create elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You can use the same process, substituting creating and appending element to `document` within `Array.from()` callback.

Comment: `o[prop] = document.createElement("input");o[prop].name = prop + "[" + form.querySelector("fieldset").length + "]"; form.querySelector("fieldset")[form.querySelector("fieldset").length -1].appendChild(o[prop])`